# Is it possible to use awe.js framework with ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, augmented-reality, awe.js

I am currently working on an AR project, and awe.js was recommended for me by many people because of how good it is. Is it possible to embed an awe.js app in a ruby on rails view?? Is there a better substitute??

Comment: Yes, any JavaScript library can be used in a Rails app.

Comment: @sevenseacat I haven't done this before, can you give me a quick overview of how i can?

Answer (score 0):

In your application.js file under javascript/assets you can use require statements (I suppose by coffee script syntax) like this:

```
//= require awejsfile
```

There, in awejsfile have all the code needed to run the awe.js commands in mind.